# After called Peek method, the origin data has changed

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "io"
    "golang.org/x/net/html/charset"
    "golang.org/x/text/encoding"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/text/transform"
    "io/ioutil"
)
// main 
func main() {
    resp, err := http.Get("http://www.baidu.com")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    if resp.StatusCode != http.StatusOK {
        fmt.Println("Error: status code", resp.StatusCode)
        return
    }

    e := determineEncoding(resp.Body)
    utf8Reader := transform.NewReader(resp.Body, e.NewDecoder())

    all, err := ioutil.ReadAll(utf8Reader)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", all)
}

// determine
func determineEncoding(r io.Reader) encoding.Encoding {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(r)
    // The start position was not correct
    bytes, err := reader.Peek(1024)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    e, _, _ := charset.DetermineEncoding(bytes, "")

    return e
}
```

The result is not correct data. The start position is not zero.
As document describe 'Peek returns the next n bytes without advancing the reader. The bytes stop being valid at the next read call. If Peek returns fewer than n bytes, it also returns an error explaining why the read is short. The error is ErrBufferFull if n is larger than b's buffer size.'

Answer (score 2):

> Peek returns the next n bytes without advancing the reader.

This refers to the `*bufio.Reader`, not the underlying reader. The buffered reader *will* read from the underlying reader if necessary. How else would it return the bytes?

In your case, you have to stop using the response body directly after calling `determineEncoding` and use the *bufio.Reader instead.

For instance:

```
func determineEncoding(r *bufio.Reader) encoding.Encoding {
    bytes, err := r.Peek(1024)

    // as before
}

func main() {
    // as before

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    r := bufio.NewReader(resp.Body)
    e := determineEncoding(r)
    utf8Reader := transform.NewReader(r, e.NewDecoder())

    // as before
}
```